# Laravel 6 Migration problem: Foreign Key Constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: laravel, eloquent, database-migration

I know this question has been asked a lot and I have tried all the answers, I just can't seem to debug this problem I am having.

I have a migration called create_product_image_table

```
class CreateProductImageTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_image', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->string('image_url');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('products')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_image');
    }
}
```

The other migration called create_products_table

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->text('product_description');
            $table->decimal('product_cost', 8, 2);
            $table->decimal('product_price', 8, 2);
            $table->bigInteger('unit_sold')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('UPC')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_image_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_image_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('product_image')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

They both have the same unsigned big integer type.  After changing the date when the migration was created and deleted the table and later the database itself, I just can't seem to pass Errno 150 error.

Thanks for your help.

Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `products_table` has a relationship with `product_image_table`,

And `product_image_table` belongs to `products_table`.

So you need to define the relation only on `product_image_table`.

You need to create  `products_table`first, and it will look like :

```
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('product_name');
            $table->text('product_description');
            $table->decimal('product_cost', 8, 2);
            $table->decimal('product_price', 8, 2);
            $table->bigInteger('unit_sold')->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('UPC')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_image_id')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

Then you need to create `product_image_table`, which will look like :

```
class CreateProductImageTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_image', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
            $table->string('image_url');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreign('product_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('products')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_image');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works.  So if a table A belongs to table B, you don't set up a foreign key on table B just table A?  I guess I am still confused with how to define linkages among tables.

Comment: @ThomasBockhorn yes

Answer (score 1):

Adde default string length in your AppServiceProvider

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {  

        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }

}
```

Comment: Default string length was already fixed before I tried to link the tables.  defaultStringLength just insures that bigIntegers can be used for the id of a table.